# Filtro de mes con fecha dividida

Tags: php

Hola tengo este detalle de hacer un filtro con solo mes tengo un campo fecha (Y-m-d)y otro campo mes del cual saque del campo fecha dividiendo en partes la fecha para solo imprimir el mes el cual imprimí el mes con numero después lo pase a letra ,ahora quiero realizar el filtro por mes pero no se como hacer la consulta ?
aquí esta mi input que es el filtro del mes

```html
<td>Mes:<input value="Mes"type="month" name="mes" id="mes"></td> 
<td><input type="submit" value="Mostrar" name="mostrar" id="mostrar" >
```

despues esta es mi división de mi fecha

```
$mostrarso=mysql_query($so);
while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
$nombremes=strftime("%B", strtotime($fecha_mes=$i[1]));
$fecha_mes=$i[1];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]}"
```

he tratado de hacer mi consulta pero no resulta

```
  if(($_POST['mes']=="") && ($_POST[$nombremes]==""))
  {
      $consulta="";
   }else
   { 
      $consulta="AND date_format(s.fecha,'%m') BETWEEN '".$_POST['mes']."' AND '".$_POST["s.fecha"]."'";
   }
```

Comment: No sé por qué te sigues empeñando en ignorar elementos que tiene PHP para ayudarte en casos como estos. Si me hubieras hecho caso desde la primera pregunta te habrías ahorrado muchas horas de esfuerzo en un código realmente penoso como es todas las manipulaciones que haces para dividir, sub-dividir, redividir, etc, etc. En una de tus preguntas te hablé sobre el uso de objetos, y de que convenía trabajar las fechas como objetos `DateTime`. Eso te permite luego a partir de ese objeto, sacar lo que quieras usando por ejemplo `format`. No sé por qué persistes en hacerlo de este modo tan precario.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte ,soy novata tal vez por eso no te e entendió ,pero gracias por el aporte disculpa por no tener en cuenta .

Comment: No hay problema. He visto que has publicado varias preguntas con el mismo problema de la fecha y creo que es por eso, porque si de entrada entendieras la enorme posibilidad que te da un objeto te ayudaría muchísimo en la programación. El concepto es simple, a partir de una cadena como `2018-11-18` creas un objeto `DateTime`, y a partir de ese objeto puedes hacer la representación que sea: mes, año, día. Puedes hacer cálculos, puedes establecerle zonas horarias, etc. Pero es siempre el mismo objeto, no tienes cada vez que reinventar tú la rueda, sino usar el objeto que ya tienes.